# how to store dictionary keys and values in a given format

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I need to store the key and values in a list

for example:

```
 dic = {'name':['Jon', 'max'],'add':['sector1','sector2']}
```

I need to extract each key and its value and store in a list

```
 output = [['name;jon;max'],[add;sector1;sector2]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking for a simpler solution then you can use this

```
Data = {'name':['Jon', 'max'],'add':['sector1','sector2']}

output = []

for key, value in Data.items():
    formated = key + ";"
    formated += ";".join(value)
    output.append([formated])
```

Comment: I'm not an expert but nested `for loops` don't quite match the definition of simpler.

Comment: yep, I will edit it so that I can get rid of the nested loop

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it:

```
>>> d = {'name':['Jon', 'max'],'add':['sector1','sector2']}
>>> [[";".join((k, *v))] for k, v in d.items()]
```

Output:

```
[['name;Jon;max'], ['add;sector1;sector2']]
```

Comment: that you so much @baduker